# error: /.../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/rubicon-icon-font.ttf: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, react-native, build, react-native-ios, native-base

I'm having error building a fresh ios cloned repository. Days before this, it was working fine. Now I tried re-installing the `native-base` or removing `node_modules` and doing `npm install` again. But still having the error:

```
2018-05-10 12:07:07.983 xcodebuild[71799:432389]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14095/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContext.mm:757
Details:  unexpected successful exit code from cancelled command <C0038:'CpResource Lato-Bold.ttf':P10>
Object:   <PBXTargetBuildContext: 0x7fd2dfe53830>
Method:   -createCommandInvocationRecordFromInvocation:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd2df8641a0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CpResource /Users/sample_user/Documents/repos/mobile/node_modules/native-base/Fonts/rubicon-icon-font.ttf build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleApp.app/rubicon-icon-font.ttf
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sampleApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Here are my versions:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.47.2

"native-base": "^2.3.1",

pod version: 1.4.0
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

I still got unexplainable errors after so I solved this by manually downloading `rubicon-icon-font.ttf` and pasted it in `node_modules\native-base\Fonts\`

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed on `master`, you can find it in today's release

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1850

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after I upgraded Native Base. The solution was to delete the missing files from XCode under Resources.